# Reusing socket descriptor on connection failure

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In my client code, I am following these steps to connect to a socket:

1. Creating a socket

   ```
   sockDesc = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
   ```
2. Connecting it (retry for 'x' time in case of failure)

   ```
   connect(sockDesc, (sockaddr *) &destAddr, sizeof(destAddr))
   ```

   (After filling the `destAddr` fields)
3. Using the socket for `send()`/`recv()` operation:

   ```
   send(sockDesc, buffer, bufferLen, 0)  
   recv(sockDesc, buffer, bufferLen, 0)
   ```
4. `close()` the socket descriptor and exit

   ```
   close(sockDesc)
   ```

If during `send()`/`recv()` the connection breaks, I found that I could connect by returning to step 2.

Is this solution okay? should I close the socket descriptor and return to step 1?

Another interesting observation that I am not able to understand is when 
I stop my echo server and start the client. I create a Socket (step 1) and call `connect()` which fails (as expected) but then I keep calling `connect()`, lets say, 10 times. After 5 retries I start the server and `connect()` is successful. But during the `send()` call it receives `SIGPIPE` error. I would like to know:

1) Do I need to create a new socket every time `connect()` fails? As per my understanding as long as I have not performed any `send()`/`recv()` on the socket it is as good as new and I can reuse the same `fd` for the `connect()` call.

2) I don't understand why `SIGPIPE` is received when the server is up and `connect()` is successful.

Comment: After changing the code as suggested closing scoket-descriptor and creatign new socket and connecting it, the SIGPIPE issue is no longer occurring.

Comment: I found this link useful and related with your question as you used send instead of write:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048959/write-and-send-solving-errors-difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should close and go back to step 1:

> close() closes a file descriptor,
>   so that it no longer refers to any
>   file and may be reused.

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close).

Comment: Any specific reason? As I am using the same fd in the connect call to reconnect with the server and not creating any new socket, it should not harm? or in this case socket goes into wait state or something?

Comment: Well the specifications suggest that the "file" no longer refers to anything. To me this indicates that the handle is still valid however it needs to be re-initialized.

Answer (score 5):

I think closing the socket is the right thing to do, despite the fact that it may work if you don't.

A socket which has failed to connect may not be in EXACTLY the same state as a brand new one - which could cause problems later. I'd rather avoid the possibility and just make a new one. It's cleaner.

TCP sockets hold a LOT of state, some of which is implementation-specific and worked out from the network.

Answer (score 4):

Sockets corresponding to broken connection is in unstable state. normally you will not be allowed to connect to again unless the operating system release the socket.

I think it will be better to close() and connect again.. you don't have to create another socket.

Anyway, make sure to set LINGER of your socket to ensure that no data is lost in transmision.

See http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Socket_002dLevel-Options.html#Socket_002dLevel-Options

Comment: If i close the descriptor, i think i need to create the socket again because closing the descriptor means destroying the socket, right?

Comment: After a socket had been `close()`d you shall not use the socket descriptor anymore. It is invalid then. Use `socket()` to aquire a new socket descriptor.

Answer (score 3):

If the connection was broken and you try to write on the file descriptor you should get the broken pipe error/signal. All this is saying is that the file descriptor you tried writing to no longer has anyone on the other side to read what you are sending.

What you can do is catch the signal SIGPIPE and then deal with the reconnecting by closing the FD and going back to your step 1. You will now have a new FD you can read and write from for the connection.

Answer (score 2):

If the Single UNIX Specification doesn't say that it MUST work to go back to step #2 instead of step #1, then the fact that it happens to work on Linux is just an implementation detail, and you would be far better off and more portable if you go back to step #1. As far as I am aware, the specification does not make any guarantee that it is ok to go back to step #2 and, therefore, I would advise you to go back to step #1.